Finding splitting field of $x^3-x+1$ and $x^3-x-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$
I am working on a text book problem from Dummit and Foote and need to define an isomorphism explicitly between the splitting field of $(x^3-x+1)$ and $(x^3-x-1)$.
I am stuck, here is my idea. I know the polynomials are degree 3 so they must have at most 3 roots. I work with the first one and I calculated the determinant of $x^3-x+1$ and seen that it must have 1 real root and 2 complex root. I solved for them but they arent in an ideal form to work with. So, I think I should just let $r_1,r_2,r_3$ be distinct roots of $x^3-x+1$. Then we have its splitting fields $\mathbb{F}_3(r_1,r_2,r_3)$ which is of degree 3 because $x^3-x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$.
But I can not find a explicit structure of $\mathbb{F}_3$. Any hint would be really helpful.
And also, I really wanted to say the splitting field of them are the two extension field, $\mathbb{F}_3$ quotient out by the ideal generated w.r.t. each polynomial. But I read on page 537 of dummit and Foote an example where the extension field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ do not contain all its roots, so it is not a splitting field of $x^3-2$. So I am really not sure if $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3-x+1)$ is the splitting field or is $\mathbb{F}_3(r_1,r_2,r_3)$, or they are the same. But I think they are not the same because this polynomial has complex root and clearly $\mathbb{F}_3$ has no complex number. But I am not sure.

If you are working over $\mathbb{F}_3$ then you don't have "real roots" and "complex roots". None of the roots are in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $\mathbb{C}$. You can simply call a root of $x^3-x+1$ something, say $\alpha$. Then the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$ (check); then you want to find a root of $x^3-x-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$.

If $u$ is a root, then $u^3$ is a root, and $u^9$ is a root.

It makes no sense to talk about "real roots" and "complex roots" when you are working over a finite field.
Because $p(x)=x^3-x+1$ has degree $3$, it is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$ if and only if it has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_3$. A quick check verifies that this is the case, as $0-0+1\neq 0$, $1-1+1\neq 1$, and $-1+1+1\neq 0$. Same for $q(x) = x^3-x-1$.
Let $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$ be an extension obtained by adjoining a root $\alpha$ of $p(x)$ to $\mathbb{F}_3$ (e.g., take $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(p(x))$, identify $\mathbb{F}_3$ with the images of the constant polynomials in the quotient, and $\alpha$ with the image of $x$ in the quotient). In this field, the polynomial splits:
$$x^3-x+1 = (x-\alpha)(x-(\alpha+1))(x-(\alpha-1)).$$
To verify the last equality, note that $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha-1$ are roots of $x^3-x+1$:
$$\begin{align*}
(\alpha+1)^3 - (\alpha+1) + 1 &= \alpha^3 + 1 - \alpha-1 +1\\
&= (\alpha-1) - \alpha + 1 = 0\\
(\alpha-1)^3 - (\alpha-1) + 1 &= \alpha^3 -1 -\alpha+1 + 1\\
&= (\alpha-1)-\alpha + 1,
\end{align*}$$
where we have used that $\alpha^3 = \alpha-1$, since $\alpha^3-\alpha+1=0$.
Similarly, one can show that any field that contains a root $\beta$ of $q(x)$ will contain all three roots.  (In fact, finite fields have the surprising property that if $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field, and $p(x)\in\mathbb{F}[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial, then any extension of $\mathbb{F}$ that has at least one root of $p(x)$ has all roots of $p(x)$. But if you don't know that yet, then the above establishes it explicitly in this case.)
So it is enough to find a root to $x^3-x-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]$. And for example,
$$(-\alpha+1)^3 - (-\alpha+1) - 1 = -\alpha^3 + 1 + \alpha - 1 - 1 = -(\alpha-1)+\alpha-1 = 0.$$
(It's not the only one... since there are three of them. Any will do!)
From this, you should be able to figure out what the map $\mathbb{F}_3[\alpha]\to\mathbb{F}_3[\beta]$ "should" be, and then you can verify that it is indeed an isomorphism.

In the second paragraph, I believe you meant $1-1+1\neq0$, since of course, it does equal $1$ :)

Thanks! this clears a lot questions. Everything makes sense, except that part where you said the polynomial splits with $\alpha \pm 1$. I do see that they are indeed roots in the quotient but what were the logic of knowing the other 2 roots are $\alpha \pm 1$?

I guess, my confusion is: doesnt the quotient field has all element in form of $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}_3$, and before plugging them into the polynomial what would tell me the other 2 roots are simply $\alpha \pm 1$ out of all those elements? Sorry if this is some trivial question but I really dont see it. I was guessing by long division, which I checked has a remainder of $\alpha ^3-\alpha+1$ which I guess is zero in the quotient field.

@RemuX The un-clever way to do it is to divide $x^3-x+1$ by $x-\alpha$ to get $x^3-x+1 = (x-\alpha)(x^2 +\alpha x +(\alpha^2-1))$ and then use the quadratic formula (which works since the characteristic is not $2$) to get the result. That's what I did. The clever way is to note that $\alpha^3=\alpha-1$ is also a root, and hence so is $(\alpha -1)^3=\alpha^3-1=\alpha+1$, which I didn't notice until later.

@RemuX As to noticing that if $\alpha$ is a root then so is $\alpha^3$, this follows because the map $a\mapsto a^p$ is an automorphism of any finite field of characteristic $p$ and that the elements that are mapped to themselves are precisely the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$. So if $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x) = a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{F}_p$, then it is also a root of $p(x^3) = a_0+a_1x^3+\cdots + a_nx^{3n} = (a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n)^3$.

Let $a$ be a root of $x^3-x+1$ in some extension $K=\Bbb F_3[a]$ of $F=\Bbb F_3$. Then the other two roots are $a+1$ and $a-1$.
Let $b$ be a root of $x^3-x-1$ in some extension $L=\Bbb F_3[b]$ of $F=\Bbb F_3$. Then the other two roots are $b+1$ and $b-1$.
Consider the morphisms:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f&:K\to L\ , &f(a)=-b\ ,\\
g&:L\to K\ , &g(b)=-a\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The morphisms are well defined, since the morphisms of rings...

$F[A]\to F[B]$, $A\to -B$ maps the polynomial
$A^3-A+1$ which generates the ideal $(A^3-A+1)$
to $(-B)^3-(-B)+1=-(B^3-B-1)$,
which is in the ideal generated by $(B^3-B-1)$, and

$F[B]\to F[A]$, $B\to -A$ maps the polynomial
$B^3-B-1$ which generates the ideal $(B^3-B-1)$
to $(-A)^3-(-A)-1=-(A^3+A-1)$,
which is in the ideal generated by $(A^3-A+1)$


... are factorizing to the corresponding quotient rings

$F[A]/(A^3-A+1)\cong F[a]=K$, $A\to a$, and
$F[B]/(B^3-B-1)\cong F[b]=L$, $B\to b$.

It is clear that $f,g$ are inverse to each other.

Both polynomials are irreducible,  because neither has a root in $\Bbb F_3.$
Adjoining a root $\alpha $ (of either) gives a degree $3$ extension $\Bbb F_3(\alpha)\cong \Bbb F_{27}.$
But $\Bbb F_{27}$ is in fact the splitting field,  in both cases:
Since the Frobenius automorphism $f(x)=x^3$ gives $f(\alpha +1)=\alpha^3 +1$ and $f(\alpha +2)=\alpha ^3+2^3=\alpha^3+2,$ an easy computation gives that $\alpha +1,\alpha +2$ are the other roots, in both cases.
Or, if you know algebraic extensions of finite fields are normal,  you can avoid the computation.
